# Do I understand correctly that simulation volume influences relative permittivity calculations? If so, how is the result useful?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, aqueous-solution, dipole, molecular-dynamics

I am having a lot of trouble understanding the influence of volume on relative permittivity/static dielectric constant.  I'm not a chemist, but am using molecular dynamics to calculate relative permittivity for use in other work.

A predecessor used this equation for relative permittivity $ε_\mathrm{r}$:

$$ε_\mathrm{r} = 1 + \frac{4π\sigma_M}{3k_\mathrm{B}TV}$$

where $V$ is the volume of the simulation, $T$ is temperature, $\sigma_M$ is the variance of the total dipole moment, and $k_\mathrm{B}$ is the Boltzmann constant.

**Here is what I do not understand:**  If I use a different $V $(i.e., a different number of atoms) for my simulation compared to my predecessor, then my calculated relative permittivity will be different from his.  I have done this to make sure, and indeed, the difference is quite significant.

Is there something silly I am misunderstanding here?  Like "$V$" is not the average box/cell volume of the simulation, but something that is not size-dependent?

Comment: Your equation looks right. It is the same as can be found in this paper, https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1009/1009.5958.pdf.

I am not certain of this, but I would guess that the variance of the total dipole moment would change when you change the total volume, and thus your result should be more or less volume independent.

Comment: Thanks very much, Erik.  I wondered if that were meant to be the case.  So then does it seem likely to you that when two calculations (each with a different number of atoms) lead to different calculated values, that the system volume is too small for one of the calculations?

Comment: And a follow-up question to that for anyone who is interested: would it make sense to run the smaller system for longer to achieve the same relative permittivity value as the larger system?  Or is there something more fundamental that's a problem about using a smaller system?

Comment: It's not quite clear how you determine the variance of total dipole moment. Is it just a mean square? Could you probably elaborate on this a bit further and add the exact math expression you are using in the equation?

Comment: Thank you very much for asking, andselisk, and thank you for your edits.  The molecular dynamics software I'm using outputs the total dipole moment and I'm using Python/numpty's "variance" function (e.g., "np.var") to calculate the variance.  Please feel free to ask if you would like me to add any more detail about this.

Comment: @ErikKjellgren Thank you for your edit. I couldn't figure out how to denote the  variance of the dipole moment in that formula, but you saved the day:)